# Noticed light not working in bathroom outlet. Removed outlet & there was no current

Tags: wiring

Electric current running to 3 GFCI outlets buy not to 4th GFCI & last outlet on circuit.

Comment: Are they all GFCI? Typically when you're trying to protect four outlets in one circuit you only need, or want, a GFCI on the first one. Every outlet downstream will be protected. Also you should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to participate here with upvotes for helpful info and check marks for accepted answers.

Comment: How are you testing for current? Have you checked the prior outlet to make sure the connections are good there?

Comment: @HoneyDo Depends how they're wired. There's something to be said for just attaching to LINE on all GFCI receptacles and having protection be local.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - Good point. If individually wired and not daisy-chained, line-to-load-to-line, individual GFCIs could make sense.